# scraping table data from bball reference in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the names, per, and mp values from the advanced table on this page https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/WAS/2019.html, but I can't figure out how to return and values from the table. I have tried following tutorials for similar goals, but I can't get anything to work. Here is my current code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests    

url="https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/{}/{}.html".format('ATL',2016)
response=requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table', {'id':'advanced'})
print(table)
```

but despite trying many different things, it always prints none. Here is some of the the html of the table I am trying to pull data from

[inspect on table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrTQR.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried loading the page on a browser without java script enabled ? Do you see the data you want to scrap?  The answer is NO, because that page needs JavaScript, which beautiful-soup doesn't have. Try selenium or similar tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have alot of knowledge in this area, usually I can just do pd.read_html and it will grab all the tables on the page..as the comments say, might have something to do with the formatting of the page??

however, if this is a one time thing, you can use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

url='https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/WAS/2019.html'
response=requests.get(url).content
soup = bs(response)

advanced = soup.find('div',{'id':'all_advanced'}).contents[5]
df = pd.read_html(advanced)[0]
```

output:

```
    Rk        Unnamed: 1  Age   G    MP   PER    TS%   3PAr    FTr  ...  OWS  DWS   WS  WS/48  Unnamed: 22  OBPM  DBPM   BPM  VORP
0    1      Bradley Beal   25  82  3028  20.8  0.581  0.370  0.278  ...  5.9  1.7  7.6  0.120          NaN   3.9  -1.1   2.8   3.7
1    2  Tomáš Satoranský   27  80  2164  14.1  0.590  0.306  0.302  ...  3.8  0.9  4.7  0.104          NaN   0.4  -1.0  -0.6   0.8
2    3        Jeff Green   32  77  2097  13.6  0.608  0.466  0.300  ...  2.8  0.8  3.6  0.083          NaN   0.2  -1.4  -1.2   0.4
3    4     Thomas Bryant   21  72  1496  21.0  0.674  0.197  0.273  ...  4.3  1.3  5.6  0.178          NaN   1.2   0.4   1.6   1.3
4    5      Trevor Ariza   33  43  1465  13.0  0.538  0.580  0.238  ...  1.1  0.8  1.9  0.062          NaN   0.6  -0.8  -0.2   0.7
5    6       Otto Porter   25  41  1191  15.0  0.551  0.398  0.145  ...  1.0  1.1  2.1  0.085          NaN  -0.2   0.3   0.1   0.6
6    7         John Wall   28  32  1104  18.0  0.527  0.306  0.317  ...  0.5  0.7  1.2  0.051          NaN   1.1  -1.2  -0.2   0.5
7    8   Markieff Morris   29  34   883  12.3  0.543  0.439  0.223  ...  0.4  0.5  0.9  0.051          NaN  -1.1  -1.0  -2.0   0.0
8    9      Bobby Portis   23  28   768  15.3  0.530  0.333  0.132  ...  0.2  0.7  0.9  0.058          NaN  -1.4  -1.4  -2.8  -0.2
9   10       Kelly Oubre   23  29   755  13.3  0.545  0.433  0.279  ...  0.3  0.5  0.8  0.053          NaN  -1.7  -1.9  -3.6  -0.3
10  11    Chasson Randle   25  49   743   9.9  0.555  0.530  0.286  ...  0.4  0.2  0.6  0.041          NaN  -1.4  -3.0  -4.4  -0.4
11  12        Troy Brown   19  52   730  11.1  0.487  0.295  0.201  ...  0.2  0.4  0.6  0.039          NaN  -2.6  -1.2  -3.7  -0.3
12  13     Austin Rivers   26  29   683   6.8  0.490  0.546  0.237  ... -0.4  0.2 -0.2 -0.014          NaN  -3.0  -1.5  -4.6  -0.4
13  14     Jabari Parker   23  25   682  17.0  0.587  0.284  0.267  ...  0.3  0.6  0.9  0.063          NaN  -0.8   0.1  -0.7   0.2
14  15        Sam Dekker   24  38   619  13.2  0.514  0.236  0.173  ...  0.4  0.4  0.8  0.059          NaN  -1.6  -0.9  -2.5  -0.1
15  16       Ian Mahinmi   32  34   498  12.0  0.531  0.154  0.587  ...  0.5  0.5  1.0  0.092          NaN  -2.3   1.3  -1.0   0.1
16  17      Jordan McRae   27  27   333  14.3  0.550  0.269  0.269  ...  0.3  0.2  0.5  0.066          NaN  -1.9  -1.8  -3.7  -0.1
17  18     Dwight Howard   33   9   230  17.4  0.638  0.000  0.696  ...  0.4  0.2  0.6  0.124          NaN  -2.9  -2.3  -5.2  -0.2
18  19    Wesley Johnson   31  12   157   2.0  0.372  0.650  0.250  ... -0.3  0.0 -0.2 -0.075          NaN  -6.3  -1.5  -7.7  -0.2
19  20       Jason Smith   32  12   130  11.7  0.520  0.270  0.324  ...  0.1  0.1  0.2  0.070          NaN  -2.9  -0.3  -3.2   0.0
20  21    Devin Robinson   23   7    95  20.6  0.616  0.063  0.438  ...  0.2  0.1  0.3  0.175          NaN  -0.2   1.2   1.0   0.1
21  22         Ron Baker   25   4    45  -2.0  0.000  1.000  0.000  ... -0.1  0.0 -0.1 -0.120          NaN  -8.8   0.8  -8.1  -0.1
22  23       Gary Payton   26   3    16  36.9  0.688  0.250  0.000  ...  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.358          NaN   9.8   5.2  14.9   0.1
23  24      John Jenkins   27   4    14  20.5  1.500  1.000  0.000  ...  0.1  0.0  0.1  0.202          NaN   7.4  -5.3   2.2   0.0
24  25       Okaro White   26   3     6  -4.5  0.000  1.000  0.000  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.251          NaN -11.0  -8.2 -19.2   0.0
```

Comment: mm seems something got screwed up..ill try to fix

Comment: fixed it for the link in the OP description, but it will also work for the url in your code

Comment: I keep getting errors that I need lxml which I am having trouble installing, Ill keep working on it. But, this looks great. Thanks so much

Comment: this not working? https://pypi.org/project/lxml/  ... or https://pypi.org/project/lxml/3.5.0/